# Reference request: convergence of moments for infinite moments.

Tags: probability-theory

If possible I'd just like a reference to read more about my problem which I'm sure must have been studied before.

I have two time-dependent random variables $X_{1}(t)$ and $X_{2}(t)$, both with continuous densities over $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, with $n$th moments $m_{1}^{n}(t)$ and $m_{2}^{n}(t)$. As $t \rightarrow \infty$
\begin{gather}
\frac{m_{1}^{n}(t)}{m_{2}^{n}(t)}\rightarrow 1+O(e^{-t})
\end{gather}
but for every $n$, that is every order of moment, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty }m_{1}^{n}(t)=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }m_{1}^{n}(t)=\infty$. However in both cases all moments are finite for any finite $t$.

My goal is to say something like $P(X_{1}(t)<x)\sim P(X_{2}(t)<x)$, but perhaps this is too ambitious.

Comment: What do you mean by $X_{1}(t)\xrightarrow[]{d} X_{2}(t)$? In order words, which parameter is suppose to converge?

Comment: Good question. I mean for any $x$ that $P(X_{1}(t)<x)\sim P(X_{2}(t)<x)$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$. I've edited the question to clear that up.